# Storing Data in Model & Call from Collection & Fetch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Collection

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone){
    console.log("Loaded");

    var Jobs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function () {
            return 'http://domain.com/api/jobs?page='+this.page+''
        },
        page: 1
    });
    return Jobs;
});
```

Model

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone){
    var JobFilterModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            T: '1',  
            PT: '1',  
            C: '1',  
            I: '1'  
        }
    });
    // Return the model for the module
    return JobFilterModel;
});
```

In one of my view , i SET the models

```
 var jobListFilterModelUpdate = new JobListFilterModel();
            jobListFilterModelUpdate.set({value:isChecked});
```

I'm trying to retrieve the MODEL from Collection so i can send the correct QUERY with the URL.

**Question 1**

How do i retrieve from Model from Collection

**Question 2**

My Fetch is in Controller(List)View , I updated the Model of Filter with

```
  var jobListFilterModelUpdate = new JobListFilterModel();
            jobListFilterModelUpdate.set({value:isChecked});
```

Now the model has be updated, with the new set of data instead of the old default.  of as above. What i'm asking is if i MANAGE to retrieve the data from model(the updated data) Will the data still be whatever i set from that Controller(List)View (at least for this "session")

Comment: You need to clarify some things - 1. Are you new to backbone? There are some obvious mistakes in your code. If you are an advanced coder, you'll need to seek answers from higher experts. 2. What do you mean by storing the data in the Models? RAM can ever be temporary storage only. You, of course, need to persist it somewhere if you want to use it some other day.

Comment: @Chandranshu Thank you, yes i definitely will , but i got some questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a long reply. Please bear with me.

> **Question 1**
>
> How do i retrieve from Model from Collection

You first need to update your Collection definition like this:

```
var Jobs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: JobFilterModel, /*This was missing before.*/
        url: function () {
            return 'http://domain.com/api/jobs?page='+this.page+''
        },
        page: 1
    });
```

After that, you get your model from a collection object like this:

```
var job = jobs.get(110);
```

In the above code, 110 is the id of the model which you want. By now, it should be clear to you that all models should have an id attribute set by the server in the JSON response it sends.

> **Question 2**
>
> Will the retrieved collection be the updated Model with the data i Set
>   in View?

What does it even mean for a collection to be a model? An apple can't be the apple tree or vice versa. Let me just say that this question is an oxymoron and then try to answer the real question bothering you.

You can either fetch one instance of a model from the server or you can get a whole bunch of them using an object of the collection. When you fetch models using a collection object, the data returned by the server is parsed and stored on the collection's models attribute. You can call `collection.models` to get the raw array of models but the preferred approach is to use `collection.get`.

On the other hand, when you create a model on the client side, it's an empty object. You can add attributes to it using `set()`. But this model object is still ephemeral and will go away when you leave the page in the browser. To persist its data, you need to call the `save()` method. `save()` uses `sync()` to persist the data to whatever datastore you want. By default, it will POST your data back to the server. By overriding the default behavior of `sync()`, you'll be able to save data to localStorage if you want.

One last thing, model instances created on the client side will not become part of a collection by default. You need to use the `add()` method of a collection object to add that model to the existing collection.

**UPDATE** to answer the questions in comments:

> I updated Question 2 and i dont understand the 110 is the id of the
>   model, my model doesnt send or receive any json. My controller does.

Yes, the controller has to encode your model as json and then send it back. You have to make sure that the returned json has an id property with some value. There is a way to customize which property will be used as the identity but let's not go there yet.

> And ,if i GET after URL is being called, i cant pass the value into the URL :(

Okay, this is not clear to me. You'll have to clarify this further.

Comment: i'm new to backbone. The model i have is the default settings, when user click on a filter, it will update it by jobListFilterModelUpdate.set({value:isChecked});
I'm not aware about the model ID , currently i fetch from Controller and dont use model.

Comment: I updated Question 2 and i dont understand the  110 is the id of the model, my model doesnt send or receive any json. My controller does

Comment: And ,if i GET after URL is being called, i cant pass the value into the URL :(

Comment: Btw, thank you for assisting me out :)I appreciate your help and look forward to your advice.

Comment: I am updating the answer to answer the questions raised in comments.

Comment: Because i use Controller to Fetch and Model to Store the user's action. The URL is in Controller. If i run the Jobs.Get , it has to be after the fetch, which  means i cant add conditions based on Jobs.get and customize the url accordingly

Comment: No, you shouldn't be doing that. I'd encourage you to read the annotated Backbone source which is only about 1000 lines and very easy to understand. You will see that the URL declared in the collection is used for other things too which will break if we were going to have conditional URLs.